# Cant resolve node-modules dependencies in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I ran `npm install leankit-client` but modules arent being found. The exact error looks like this:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\xx\Desktop_REPOS\leankit-angular-test\node_modules\aws-sign2'

for quite a few modules:

- crypto
- http
- https
- net
- path
- stream

and more

How do I fix this, install each one individually? (`npm installl crypto`, etc)

**Results of npm install:**

```
 $npm install leankit-client
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ leankit-client@2.4.0
updated 1 package in 9.457s
```

Comment: Did you check the modules folder for the package you installed? Are you finding the missing folders, are some missing, or are they all missing?

Comment: Is there an error beforehand (during running `npm install`)?

Comment: @JudeDesir The crypto module appears fine (folder aws-sign2 shows up), as do most of the others when I checked

Comment: @DanielHabenicht nope, no error during npm install, but I got a few warnings I added to the post above if those help

Comment: Ok, than. Can you provide the file that the error is throw in?